Is it advisable to perform schema validation with every read operation?
I'm exploring the efficiency of schema validation in read-heavy services. Is it okay to conduct schema validation with every read operation?
Additionally, I'm curious about the relevance of schema validation in non-read heavy services. So far, it's commonly recommended to perform schema validation primarily on writes.
Could someone shed light on this distinction and the computational tradeoffs involved? Schema validation undoubtedly introduces overhead, and I'm keen in understanding these tradeoffs.
Thank you
Best approach for schema validation.

Why are you validating your schema with any database transactions?  What, exactly, do you mean by "scherma validation"?  Why is your database schema changing so rapidly?
